# Install printer driver for a wireless Canon Pixma MX340 on Fedora 21

Tags: network-printer, canon-pixma

How do I install and configure a wireless Canon printer on Fedora - specifically a PIXMA MX340 on Fedora 21? I've searched around and found that Canon provide RPMs for this printer but they're very out of date and are only 32bit

Comment: This question does not make sense.  You say you searched and the only drivers you found were out of date, then 4 minutes later you indicate you performe a quick search and discovered them the link to a personal blog which I assume has links to the drivers.  This seems like an attempt to drive traffic to your blog.

Comment: @Ramhound The user is saying he searched probably because he already knew the answer and had to write a question about the problem. (See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @slhck - I have no problem with self-answered questions.  I just have a problem with self-answered questions, which indicate the author looked for a driver but found no results, then 4 minutes later submitting an answer saying they performed a search and located them.  If the only thing it contained was the first sentence, which is a question, I would find the question helpful instead of confusing.

Comment: @Ramhound I was just trying to help other people who had the same issue. I found plenty of posts about how to force the Canon drivers to work at great difficulty. After finding the solution with gutenprint I decided to write a quick blog article and then record the solution here too as a self answered question. I'll leave the link off next time. I don't think I deserve to be down voted by doing something that StackExchange supports

Comment: @AndrewDwyer - Which is the reason I didn't down vote your answer only your question because of the approach you took, I shared my concerns with how the question is written, easy enough to address those concerns.  The answer no longer has a link to your blog, it was self contained, and thus is a decent enough answer so it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick `yum search canon` and found `gutenprint-cups.x86_64 : CUPS drivers for Canon, Epson, HP and compatible printers`. A quick google shows me that my printer is supported.

Just install the package:

`sudo yum install gutenprint-cups.x86_64`

Then add the printer from the system settings by entering the IP address. If the printer is on the system should be able to find it. Just select it and find the model number in the list of canon printers provided by Guten Print.

Comment: -1 because this is not an answer. Write it as comment please.

Comment: @duDE - Technically its more of an answer then a comment except it also appears to be an attempt to draw traffic to the linked website which happens to be the author's blog.  I don't disagree the anwer should sustain itself and it currently does not do that.

Comment: @AndrewDwyer I agree with Ramhound, there is no need to include the link to your blog, since you answer would be equally complete without it.  Then add to that the lack of effort shown in the question...

Comment: We have a regular Stack Exchange user here, and I don't see any bad intentions. Andrew clearly found a solution that he wanted to share with others. The purpose of this post does not seem to be to draw traffic to the blog. I agree the link is not necessary though.